# Can partial function application be lazy in the sense that it does not recompute the same partial evaluation twice?

Tags: scala, haskell

Why is partial evaluation not strictly evaluated in the moment of the partial application and why is it re-evaluated more than once?
As a hipster question, examples in Scala and Haskell (for a moment I thought Haskell would behave differently):

In Scala:

```
scala> def f(x: Int)(y: Int) = {println("inside"); x * y}
f: (x: Int)(y: Int)Int

scala> val f2 = f(2) _ 
f2: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> f2(3)
inside                     //internals of f calculated for the first time
res7: Int = 6

scala> f2(7)
inside                     //internals of f recalculated
res8: Int = 14
```

In Haskell:

```
  Prelude> import Debug.Trace

  Prelude Debug.Trace> let f x y = trace "inside" x * y

  Prelude Debug.Trace> let f2 = f 2

  Prelude Debug.Trace> f2 3
  inside                   //internals of f calculated for the first time
  6

  Prelude Debug.Trace> f2 3
  inside                   //internals of f recalculated
  6

  Prelude Debug.Trace> f2 7
  inside                   //internals of f recalculated
  14
```

I know it is possible to redefine `f` to return a function like in code below, but it would be interesting to have functions that are **really** partially evaluated even before they are *completely evaluated*:

```
scala> def f(x: Int) = {println("inside"); (y:Int) => x * y}
f: (x: Int)Int => Int

scala> val f2 = f(2)
inside                           //internals of f calculated only this time
f2: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> f2(3)
res12: Int = 6

scala> f2(7)
res13: Int = 14
```

Comment: The thing you're looking for is called "fully lazy" (a term coined by John Hughes, I think).  Some implementations have it, most don't.

Comment: The reason the full laziness transformation is not usually performed is that it can lead to space leaks that are difficult to find and/or fix. I don't remember why.

Comment: @augustss: I could not find anything about "fully lazy". Do you know a more precise reference?

Comment: Google "full laziness"

Comment: @augustss: thanks. I found that GHC already do something [ghc optm.](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/users_guide/options-optimise.html). This [other site](http://foldoc.org/full+laziness) explains the problem far better than my question.

Answer (score 14):

In Haskell, yes.  You have to be careful about exactly what lambda expressions your function definition desugars to.  For example

```
Prelude> import Debug.Trace
Prelude Debug.Trace> let f x = let x1 = trace "inside" x in \y -> x1 * y
Prelude Debug.Trace> let f2 = f 2
Prelude Debug.Trace> f2 3
inside
6
Prelude Debug.Trace> f2 3
6
Prelude Debug.Trace> f2 7
14
```

An additional example suggested by Sassa NF.  Note that in `g` the `trace "inside" succ` closure is recreated each call, whereas in `h` the closure is bound to `h` once and for all.  Eta reduction does not preserve operational semantics in Haskell!

```
Prelude Debug.Trace> let g = \x -> (trace "inside" succ) x :: Int
Prelude Debug.Trace> g 1
inside
2
Prelude Debug.Trace> g 2
inside
3
Prelude Debug.Trace> g 3
inside
4
Prelude Debug.Trace> let h = trace "inside" succ :: Int -> Int
Prelude Debug.Trace> h 1
inside
2
Prelude Debug.Trace> h 2
3
Prelude Debug.Trace> h 3
4
```

Comment: I suppose would be good to see how to desugar `x * y`. I find it odd that `f x y = (trace "inside" x) * y` and `f x = ((trace "inside" x) *)` are not the same thing - unless `(*)` is specifically implemented to evaluate `y` first. Otherwise I'd expect applying `\x y -> x * y` to `2` to evaluare to `\y -> 2 * y`, which should evaluate to `(2 *)`.

Comment: @TomEllis: Your first example is similar to the last Scala example in the question. We are doing the partial application evaluation by ourselves! `let f x = (*) (trace "inside" x)` would seem clearer to me, but I am not an experienced haskeller. Perhaps the answer I was expecting is more in line with _augustss_ "fully lazy" suggestion.

Comment: @davips: Oh I see.  You're asking "why doesn't the compiler do this automatically?".  In that case I didn't actually answer your question.  If I were to answer it I would say "Why make the compiler translate automatically from one form to another when both forms are useful in practice and the programmer often actually wants to choose between the two?".

Comment: @TomEllis: In a stateless program, I don't see why would the programmer want the machine to evaluate repeated times the same part of a function body. Your suggested conversion can be a good simple way  to a compiler to do it behind the scenes, I guess. I found that GHC already do something [ghc optm.](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/users_guide/options-optimise.html). This [other site](http://foldoc.org/full+laziness) explains the problem far better than my question.

Comment: The full-laziness transformation is one possible source of space leaks, and it really ought not to be done automatically.  (Unfortunately in GHC it is under -O).  If the programmer wants these particular semantics they should implement them by hand.   https://www.mail-archive.com/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/msg104329.html

Comment: @TomEllis: Ok, now I got the point. The runtime would need to keep internal cached values for each evaluated function with no guarantees of reuse in the future nor when to automatically garbage collect them.

Comment: Well it won't garbage collect them between uses of the function, which may be problematic, depending on how large they are.